# Key capture in android

Tags: android

I am working on an application thats captures all the keys that are being pressed.
As of now I can capture the keys in application.
But how can I capture the keys while the application is running in android.
I am aware of services concept, but am unable to capture the keys while application in running in background.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would make sense that you aren't able to do so as it would allow you to steal users passwords that they type into other applications.